# make unique rows and append min value of some columns

Tags: r, subset, unique

I have a data frame on R. I would like to get the unique rows based on the first three columns and also append the min value of the 4th column in each unique row.

```
dat <- tibble(
  x = c("a", "a", "k", "k"),
  y = c("a", "a", "l", "l"),
  z = c("e", "e", "m" ,"m"),
  t = c("4", "3", "8" ,"9"))
```

What I would like to see is below.

| x | y | z | t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | e | 3 |
| k | l | m | 8 |

I believe there is a very easy way to do that but I can not see it at that moment.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. May I add some more questions here? If I have other columns (p,q,r) which have distinct values for each row and should be kept for the aggregated dat based on the row which has the min value of the t column, how should I modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, use `group_by` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(across(x:z)) %>% 
  summarise(t = min(t), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  x     y     z     t    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     a     e     3    
2 k     l     m     8
```

---

Or do an `arrange` and use `distinct`

```
dat %>%
  arrange(across(everything())) %>%
  distinct(across(x:z), .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  x     y     z     t    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     a     e     3    
2 k     l     m     8
```

Answer (score 0):

We may call to `apply()` to find the unique rows values *per row* in `dat`. Then, we can used `duplicated()` to look for duplicates and use the negation `!` to return rows that are *not* duplicates. We use `which` to obtain integers corresponding to the rows in `dat` that are *not* duplicates. Finally, use these integers (`unique_rows`) to extract the unique rows from `dat`. As such, we do not have to `append`.

```
unique_rows <- which(!duplicated(apply(dat[, 1:3], 1, unique)))
out <- dat[unique_rows, ]
```

**Output**

```
> out
  x y z t
1 a a e 4
3 k l m 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this would be to take minimum value of `t` column and keep remaining columns as group in `aggregate` function.

```
aggregate(t~., dat, min)

#  x y z t
#1 a a e 3
#2 k l m 8
```